# Is this the one time git disappears something forever?

Tags: git

Pretty sure it's gone for good but need confirmation before I give up..

Local changes were not added yet. I was in the Git for Windows GUI, highlighted a couple lines, meant to hit 'Revert Lines', but hit 'Revert Hunk' instead. Poof goes the whole section.

Like I said, changes were not not added or stashed or anything, so nothing in reflog. Any other tricks, or do I start over?

Lesson learned: Add immediately, even if you want to clean things up before committing!

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the Git command line.  Specifically, run `git status` (to see if there are any pending changes) and `git log` (to see the last commits)

Comment: Yep, well familiar, just being lazy in this case

Comment: Q: does `git status` confirm that your working copies are truly gone?  Does `git log` confirm they were never added before that?  Frankly, I've never used 'Revert Lines' or 'Revert Hunk'.  But I often do "filecopy backups" ;)  And the occasional `git stash` ;)  PS: Nothing "lazy" about the GUI.  It's *smart* to use the best tool.  But the Git cmd line gives you "fine control" ... in situations like this.

Comment: Is the file still open in the editor (not `vim`)? If yes, try `ctrl-z` in the editor. Don't press them repeatedly. Press once and check if the changes are back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Like I said, changes were not not added or stashed or anything, so nothing in reflog. Any other tricks, or do I start over?

If they were never added, Git never stored the changes anywhere. Even if they were added, Git does not remember changes to the index. Sorry.

If this were done in an editor with Git integration, like [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [Atom](https://atom.io/), it's possible your editor could undo the change if you still had the file open. Check to see if your GUI has an undo.

> Lesson learned: Add immediately, even if you want to clean things up before committing!

Yes, that's what the staging area is for: building the next commit. You can also commit and amend it later.